# VMware Rest API Authentication failed

Tags: rest, vmware-workstation

I am completely new to vmware rest api and have been trying it out for awhile now.

I've been following this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OHLUhaQ786I&feature=emb_title to setting the rest api and it works.

I met with a problem. In the API itself, I am able to click on try it out and get the response body and it works fine.

However, when I go to the request url itself or try to curl with cmd, all I am getting is

{
  "Code": 1,
  "Message": "Authentication failed"
}

Is there anything I've done wrong? I've googled around for hours but to no avail.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

At minute 1:19 you can see the curl command, in the command you have a header Authorization: Basic cmV...

Well, you have to use this header to complete the request in the REST API.

You can use developer mode in any browser to add the header on the request.